# Simple Javascript window opener acting crazy

Tags: javascript

Look at this script:

```
<a href="brooklyn.swf" onclick="
  window.open(
    'brooklyn.swf',
    'Start Here: Brooklyn',
    'toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,width=870,height=650,scrollbars=no'
  );
  return false">
    Launch animated presentation &gt;&gt;
</a>
```

Can anybody explain why the resizable=no does not work in Safari or Firefox (haven't tested any other browsers)? That is, the window call still be resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are opening a standalone `.swf` file in a popup window. Try to make a small HTML page containing the flash file, and use that as a popup.

Answer (score 2):

From [Mozilla window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open):

> Starting with Firefox 3, secondary windows are always resizable ([bug 177838](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177838))

It's a design decision, giving the user more control. I assume Safari have made the same decision.